# How to automatically update a column in Sharepoint when an email item is added

Tags: sharepoint

In Sharepoint, everytime a new email (.msg or .eml) file is added to a list, I want to open it and extract properties of the message and update some custom columns for the list item. Can you provide a high level view of doing this?